# Delphi 7, XML handling with Unicode support

Tags: delphi, unicode, jvcl

I'm developing in Delphi 7 (personal). I used to use JvSimpleXML for XML handling, but it doesn't seem to handle WideStrings (or does it?!). My whole project uses TntWide... & SpTBXLib for interface so it does handle Unicode very well, I need now to store some settings in files ... So I'm looking for solution or (free) replacement of JvSimpleXML ... any ideas?

Thanks in advance
michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/). I have started using it instead of msxml. It also gives you the '[FluentXMLBuilder](http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/2009/04/fluent-xml-2.html)' which is very slick.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ths lastest version of [MSXML 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xml/bb291077.aspx)(Microsoft XML Core Services)  importing the dll from delphi.

[image]

Here is an example of code generated

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IXMLDOMDocument
// Flags:     (4560) Hidden Dual NonExtensible OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {2933BF81-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}
// *********************************************************************//
  IXMLDOMDocument = interface(IXMLDOMNode)
    ['{2933BF81-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}']
    function Get_doctype: IXMLDOMDocumentType; safecall;
    function Get_implementation_: IXMLDOMImplementation; safecall;
    function Get_documentElement: IXMLDOMElement; safecall;
    procedure _Set_documentElement(const DOMElement: IXMLDOMElement); safecall;
    function createElement(const tagName: WideString): IXMLDOMElement; safecall;
    function createDocumentFragment: IXMLDOMDocumentFragment; safecall;
    function createTextNode(const data: WideString): IXMLDOMText; safecall;
    function createComment(const data: WideString): IXMLDOMComment; safecall;
    function createCDATASection(const data: WideString): IXMLDOMCDATASection; safecall;
    function createProcessingInstruction(const target: WideString; const data: WideString): IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction; safecall;
    function createAttribute(const name: WideString): IXMLDOMAttribute; safecall;
    function createEntityReference(const name: WideString): IXMLDOMEntityReference; safecall;
    function getElementsByTagName(const tagName: WideString): IXMLDOMNodeList; safecall;
    function createNode(type_: OleVariant; const name: WideString; const namespaceURI: WideString): IXMLDOMNode; safecall;
    function nodeFromID(const idString: WideString): IXMLDOMNode; safecall;
    function load(xmlSource: OleVariant): WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_readyState: Integer; safecall;
    function Get_parseError: IXMLDOMParseError; safecall;
    function Get_url: WideString; safecall;
    function Get_async: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_async(isAsync: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure abort; safecall;
    function loadXML(const bstrXML: WideString): WordBool; safecall;
    procedure save(destination: OleVariant); safecall;
    function Get_validateOnParse: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_validateOnParse(isValidating: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_resolveExternals: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_resolveExternals(isResolving: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_preserveWhiteSpace: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_preserveWhiteSpace(isPreserving: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_onreadystatechange(Param1: OleVariant); safecall;
    procedure Set_ondataavailable(Param1: OleVariant); safecall;
    procedure Set_ontransformnode(Param1: OleVariant); safecall;
    property doctype: IXMLDOMDocumentType read Get_doctype;
    property implementation_: IXMLDOMImplementation read Get_implementation_;
    property documentElement: IXMLDOMElement read Get_documentElement write _Set_documentElement;
    property readyState: Integer read Get_readyState;
    property parseError: IXMLDOMParseError read Get_parseError;
    property url: WideString read Get_url;
    property async: WordBool read Get_async write Set_async;
    property validateOnParse: WordBool read Get_validateOnParse write Set_validateOnParse;
    property resolveExternals: WordBool read Get_resolveExternals write Set_resolveExternals;
    property preserveWhiteSpace: WordBool read Get_preserveWhiteSpace write Set_preserveWhiteSpace;
    property onreadystatechange: OleVariant write Set_onreadystatechange;
    property ondataavailable: OleVariant write Set_ondataavailable;
    property ontransformnode: OleVariant write Set_ontransformnode;
  end;
```

**EDIT**

The object TXMLDocument (for delphi 7) located in XMLDoc.pas is a Wrapper of the version MSXML 4 o less.

```
const
  { GUID's from MSXML2_TLB.pas }
  CLASS_DOMDocument26: TGUID = '{F5078F1B-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}';
  CLASS_DOMDocument30: TGUID = '{F5078F32-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}';
  CLASS_DOMDocument40: TGUID = '{88D969C0-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}';

function CreateDOMDocument: IXMLDOMDocument;
begin
  Result := TryObjectCreate([CLASS_DOMDocument40, CLASS_DOMDocument30,
    CLASS_DOMDocument26, msxml.CLASS_DOMDocument]) as IXMLDOMDocument;
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise DOMException.Create(SMSDOMNotInstalled);
end;
```

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xml/bb291077.aspx) site :

> MSXML4 was introduced to add features
>   and improve performance but has been
>   superseded by MSXML6. Customers on
>   MSXML4 should look at migrating to
>   MSXML6 as soon as schedule constraints
>   allow.

Bye

Comment: You don't have to import the dll, you can use TXMLDocument and set Vendor to MSXML

Comment: the object TXMLDocument (for delphi 7) located in XMLDoc.pas is a Wrapper of the version MSXML 4. using the method described above you can use the MSXML version 6.

Comment: these wrappers are unavailable in Delphi 7 Personal which I am using. They also produce additional dependencies which I'd like to avoid...

Comment: Rruz, you can get whatever MSXML version you want by assigning a new function to the `MSXmlDom.MSXmlDomDocumentCreate` function pointer. By default, it attempts to load version 4, 3, 2.6, and 1, whichever works first.

Comment: Rob already knew, the point I wanted to note is that this option can have access to a newer version of MSXML :)

Answer (score 1):

TXMLDocument that comes with Delphi handles WideStrings/Unicode just fine. By default it uses the MSXML library mentioned here. It is a DOM like API. See http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa101904a.htm for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Affordable but not free, Storage Library @ http://www.deepsoftware.com/rsllib/ will save as XML, INI, Regitry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need checking against a XSD schema or transformation with XSL, you should check out [DIXml](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/xml/index).